# Question b show that $a_n$ diverges when $x_n<1/2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

a.  Let $0< x <1/2$ and let $∑a_n$ be a series of positive real numbers.  Assume that the sequence $(a_n)_{n∈\Bbb N}$ is decreasing and that

$$\frac{a_{2n}}{a_n} \leqslant x$$

and converges given this property, but when $x$ is replaced with

$$\frac{a_{2n}}{a_n}<\frac12$$

The series doesn't necessarily diverge. Can someone help me with this?

The answers are here but I don't understand part 2

[answers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNpa7.png)

Comment: What have you tried?  And what is your question? Does "a2n" mean $a_{2n}$ or $a_{2^n}$?  Your linked page uses both.

Comment: I tries to edit your question and get in a form where it's readable, but I had to gess, though.

Comment: Do you not understand the answer or why we're able to construct a counterexample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that we need $\frac{a_{2n}}{a_n}\to 1/2$ from (strictly) below as $n\to\infty$, since otherwise we could use the first part of the exercise to see $\sum a_n$ must converge. An obvious first candidate would be $a'_n=1/n$, since the sum diverges and we have $\frac{a'_{2n}}{a'_n}=1/2$ for all $n$. However, we want the ratio to be *strictly* less than 1/2, so we'll need to perturb our $a'_n$ a bit so that the inequality is strict but the sum still diverges. A natural guess would be to multiply it by something that approaches 1 as $n\to\infty$, and in order to get the inequality the correct way, we can let this sequence be $1+\frac{1}{n}$.

From now it's just checking whether our guess $a_n=\frac{1}{n}(1+\frac{1}{n})$ (which is positive) works.

First we check that indeed $\frac{a_{2n}}{a_n}<1/2$, but note that $$a_{2n}/a_n=1/2\frac{1+\frac{1}{2n}}{1+\frac{1}{n}}=1/2\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}<1/2,$$ since $2n+1<2n+2$.

So it suffices to see that $\sum a_n$ diverges. But note that $a_n=1/n+1/n^2>1/n$, so by the comparison test and the fact that $\sum 1/n$ diverges we get what we wanted.

Comment: Thanks you legend this has been a huge help thank you